# Updating Records in Elm ( what happened to the old one?)

Tags: elm, records

Ok first off please see the post below:

[Updating a record in Elm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37009524/updating-a-record-in-elm/37032120#37032120)

I'm more curious as to how that is actually possible since that makes the record a variable in effect, something functional programming tries to avoid?

What happened to my old bill? Someone basically deleted my x = 4 and made a new one x = boo_far?

Comment: You posted a comment as an answer, so it was deleted. That's not how Stack Overflow works. Also as it stands your question is unclear. There's nothing wrong with asking about another question or answer on Stack Overflow but you still need to ask a coherent question.

Comment: Oh I see, it was the only way I could post for some reason so I figured its the way it goes. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Functional programming avoids *mutation*. In Elm, records are not mutated, they are copied.

Even saying that they are *copied* is a bit of a misrepresentation. They are not fully *cloned* byte for byte. That would be horribly inefficient. Their internal structure is more graph-like, allowing for efficient pointer-based operations that effectively extend the underlying structures without mutating already-existing nodes and edges when you perform operations that *copy* into a new record.

Conceptually speaking, it may help to think of it this way: Once you *copy* into a new record value, the old one sticks around forever. However, our computers don't have infinite memory, and those *old* values may often go permanently unused, so we leave it to Javascript's garbage collector to clean up those old pointers.

Consider the [example in the answer given by @timothyclifford](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37009524/updating-a-record-in-elm/37032120#answer-37009699):

```elm
-- Create Bill Gates
billGates = { age = 100, name = "gates" }

-- Copy to Bill Nye
billNye = { bill | name = "Nye" }

-- Copy to a younger Bill Nye
youngBillNye = { billNye | age = 22 }
```

The internal representation could be thought of like this:

[image: all the bills]

Conceptually, you can think of those living in perpetuity. However, let's say that `billGates` gets selected for garbage deletion because it is no longer being referenced (e.g. its frame is popped from the stack). The `billGates` pointer is deleted and the `name=="gates"` node is deleted, but all other nodes and edges remain untouched:

[image: bye bye gates]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted to know.